# Windows XP RDP Protocol Error

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am trying to RDP into a windows xp pro sp3 machine (from windows 7). The connection is succesfull but after a random amount of time ( usually between 1 and 3 minutes) the session gets disconnected with the following message:

Protocol Error. Session will be disconnected.

I have no idea what is causing this protocol error and apparently it's a very rare error since I couldn't find any useful info on google. After the session gets disconnected I take a look at the logs and (every time) under system tab I find 4 new error entries

Event 1111 : Driver required for printer ______ is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.

Could these two things be related?

What do you think is causing this protocol error?

Other (possibly) useful info:
•Team viewer is installed on the xp machine (conflict?) 
•Rdp port is default 3389

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with your MTU. I've had issues with remoting/ssh when the MTU on the client is set to the default 1500.

To find out the max MTU, use the ping command, starting with `-l` as 1500, then lowering it until it returns successfully:

```
ping x.x.x.x -f -l 1500
```

To change it, use the command in cmd (In this example, im changing it to 1452:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1452 store=persistent
```

or for wireless:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Wireless Network Connection" mtu=1452 store=persistent
```